# Python: Reading lines from .txt file and calculating with them

Tags: python, file, line, with-statement

I hope you are having pleasant holidays so far!

I am trying to read a .txt file in which values are stored and separated from each other by a line skip and then calculate with the values.

I am trying to figure out how to do this using a Python script.

Let's say this is the content of my text file:

```
0.1 #line(0)
1.0
2.0
0.2 #line(3)
1.1
2.1
0.3 #line(6)
1.2
2.2
...
```

Basically I would to implement an operation that calculates:

**line(0)*line(1)*line(2)** in the first step, writes it into another .txt file and then continues with **line(3)*line(4)*line(5)** and so on:

```
with open('/filename.txt') as file_:
    for line in file_:
       for i in range(0,999,1):
           file = open('/anotherfile.txt')
           file.write(str(line(i)*line(i+1)*line(i+2) + '\n')
           i += 3
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: What's your problem at the moment? FYI, you should probably read data into your program, process it, and then write it, rather than doing both at the same time. And you need a closing paren on that `write` function.

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: which python version? 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would multiply three numbers at a time and write the product of the three into another file:

```
with open('numbers_in.txt') as fobj_in, open('numbers_out.txt', 'w') as fobj_out:
    while True:
        try:
            numbers = [float(next(fobj_in)) for _ in range(3)]
            product = numbers[0] * numbers[1] * numbers[2]
            fobj_out.write('{}\n'.format(product))
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Here `next(fobj_in)` always tries to read the next line.
If there is no more line a `StopIteration` exception is raised.
The `except StopIteration:` catches this exception and terminates the loop.
The list comprehension `[float(next(fobj_in)) for _ in range(3)]`
converts three numbers read from three lines into floating point numbers.
Now, multiplying the thee numbers is matter of indexing into the list `numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
file = open('/anotherfile.txt','w')
i=0
temp=1
with open('/filename.txt') as file_:
    for line in file_:
        temp = temp*int(line)
        if(i>1 && i%3==0):
           file.write(str(temp)+'\n')
           temp=1
        i += 1
```